# Add 'software' and 'simulation' tags

Tags: discussion, tags

I have added the [software](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software) and [simulation](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/simulation) tags to [this question](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/4518). They seem perfectly good tags for this site.

But I also know that if a newly suggested tag is not used enough, it will disappear again. Is there a way to 'fix' them?

[If my edit gets accepted, I will re-tag other questions accordingly, in the hope it 'cements' them into place]

Answer (score 2):

The only way tags get deleted is if no questions are using them.  As long as one question exists that uses the tag then the tag will stick around.

The only threat to your tags disappearing are if someone edits them out of all the questions they are attached to and waits a day for the system to check for unused tags.

Comment: There [is a process which removes tags with only 1 use after 6 months](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/48418/237685) but it seems that there are >1 question with each tag now so that doesn't matter.

Comment: I retagged a few with software just to make sure it sticks around